# How typewatch handles a submit request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, typewatch

I'm using [typewatch](https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch) on a search form. When I implement something like this

```
$('#search_groups').submit(function() {
    alert("testing");
    return false;
});
```

The alert message pops up but the submit request for the form is still processed via AJAX.  However, this is the only request that goes through almost as if by pressing return, you simply accelerate the submit timer on typewatch.  Is this what's happening here?  I looked at the typewatch [source code](https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch/blob/master/jquery.typewatch.js) but couldn't seem to find anything.   Also, when I remove the above code, the form gets submitted twice: as a JS request and as HTML.  The HTML request is going through because I'm no longer cancelling the submit action and I think the reasoning behind JS request is related to the main issue at hand: what typewatch does when the form its bound to is submitted.  Thanks a bunch!

form code:

```
<%= form_tag groups_path, method: :get, id: "search_groups" do %>
    Find a Group: <%= text_field_tag :groups_query, params[:groups_query] %>
<% end %>
```

**Update**: Found the answer and it confirmed what I thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my answer and it confirmed what I thought that the enter key "speeds" up the timer,

From the typewatch source code:

```
if (evt.keyCode == 13 && (this.type.toUpperCase() == "TEXT" || this.type.toUpperCase() == "PASSWORD")) {
timerWait = 1;
overrideBool = true;
}
```

keyCode #13 is the enter key